# Accessing local file inside a WebView in react-native

Tags: reactjs, canvas, webview, react-native

I'm sending a local file path to a webview and want to display the image inside a canvas.

I'm getting the path into my webview but can't load it, here's the message i get :

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:////Users/...

Is there any solution to access a local file or any work around ?

```
<WebView
    style={{flex:1,borderWidth:2}}
    source={require('./webview/canvas.html')}
    ref={webview => {this.webview = webview; }}
    onLoad={this._webViewLoaded.bind(this)}
    onMessage={this._getMessageFromWebView.bind(this)}
```

/>

And then sending data with :

```
this.webview.postMessage(this.state.path);
```

Where this.state.path is a local path after using the camera component

Comment: the image should be added to the project assets.

Comment: @vijayst can you give me an exemple please ?

Comment: Can you update the question with the `<WebView ... />` source? Will help me fix it in the answer.

Comment: @vijayst edited, i made a little work around by encoding the file in base64 and sending it to my webview. Works fine on simulator but not on device tho

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a work around on this problem.
Using react-native-fetch-blob :

```
RNFetchBlob
        .config({
            fileCache : false,
            appendExt : 'jpg'
        })
        .fetch('GET', this.state.path)
        .then((res) => {
            let base64Str = res.base64().then((result)=>{
                this.setState({imageBase64 : result})
                this.webview.postMessage(this.state.imageBase64);
            });
        })
```